# How to make a brush that paints graph-paper-like squares for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8

Here is the solution for WPF:

```
<DrawingBrush Viewport="0,0,20,20"
          ViewportUnits="Absolute" TileMode="Tile">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L1,0 1,0.1, 0,0.1Z" Brush="LightBlue" />
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0 L0,1 0.1,1, 0.1,0Z" Brush="LightBlue" />
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
```

But as I understand there is no DrawingBrush under WinPhone8.

Comment: did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075879/graphpaper-background-with-xaml-and-path-markup-language

Comment: There is DrawingBrush is used. As I said WinPhone SDK does not support the DrawingBrush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Path` class instead of DrawingBrush.

Examples: [msdn tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [geekCamp](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/drawing-in-wp7-3-understanding-path-shapes)

Comment: Is it possible to set the Path object to the background of the Window?

Comment: You can use `Grid` layout for Window items. And then add `Path` object to the Grid and other stuff.